# AJAX sends JS variable to PHP OK but the receiving PHP doesn't echo back to webpage

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have 2 php files.
The first contains some JavaScript which is inside an EOD tag. This code has two dynamic drop down lists with an event listener which correctly listens to when the second list item is selected.

The item selected is correctly sent to another PHP file for further processing.

This is the JS Script code in my first PHP file:

```
$js_array_leadersGroupsName = array("group1", "group2");
$js_array_students_lists = array(["Bob", "Jane"], ["Sally", "Tom"]);


$js_array_leadersGroupsName = json_encode($js_array_leadersGroupsName);
$js_array_students_lists = json_encode($js_array_students_lists);


$Content3 = <<<EOD


            <form action="" id="myGroupSelectForm" method="post">
              <select id="selectGroup">
                <option>Choose a Group</option>
              </select>
                <select id="selectStudent">
                <option>Choose a Student</option>
              </select>
            </form>

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">

            var select = document.getElementById("selectGroup"); 
            var options = {$js_array_leadersGroupsName}; 
            var i;

            for(i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                var opt = options[i];
                var el = document.createElement("option");
                el.textContent = opt;
                el.value = opt;
                select.appendChild(el);
            }

            var studentList = {$js_array_students_lists}; 
            var select2 = document.getElementById("selectStudent");

            var a = document.getElementById('selectGroup');
            a.addEventListener('change', function() {

                var i;
                for(i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                        if ((this.value) == options[i]) {
                            var chosenStudentList = studentList[i];
                        }
                    }

                var select = document.getElementById("selectStudent");
                var length = select.options.length;
                for (i = length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                  select.options[i] = null;
                }

                var i;
                for(i = 0; i < chosenStudentList.length; i++) {
                    var opt = chosenStudentList[i][0];
                    var el = document.createElement("option");
                    el.textContent = opt;
                    el.value = opt;
                    select2.appendChild(el);
                }

                }, false);

                var b = document.getElementById('selectStudent');
                b.addEventListener('change', function() {
                    var chosenSudent = this.value;
                    alert(this.value);

                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/path/to/NewFile.php',
                    data: "userID=" + chosenSudent,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert("success!");
                    }
                    });

                    }, false);



            </script>

EOD;



            $Content3 .="\n";       
            return $Content3;
```

This is the code in my second PHP File:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['userID']))
{
    $uid = $_POST['userID'];
    echo  $uid;
}
?>
```

My question:

I cannot get my second php file's echo command to display the $uid variable on the webpage after the second drop-down item is selected. How can this be done?

Comment: Just to clarify, is the ajax request triggering in the first place? In the code here you'd expect an alert with "success!" to happen after you change the select option - but you're just seeing in the ajax request in the browser that `$_POST['userID']` is always empty and looks like it's not set in the first place?

Comment: Yes that is right. It is not triggering as the success alert does not appear

Comment: Your code all checks out... the only time I could produce an error is when NewFile.php doesn't exist assuming `$js_array_leadersGroupsName` and `$js_array_students_lists` are formatted correctly.. but otherwise you wouldn't have any values in the dropdown. - maybe check the case of FileName.php is correct?

Comment: Seems ok. It is in the same directory as the first PHP file...?

Comment: Do the EOD tags cause issues for AJAX?

Comment: Ah! When you say "in the same directory as the PHP file" your ajax call needs to have the path the browser would take to the file - so for example if your browser has `/my/folder/form-page.php` even though `form-page.php` and the `submit.php` are in the same folder, the ajax file path still likely needs the full `/my/folder/submit.php` - so whatever your address in your browser is like `http://localhost/my/folder/form-page.php` you still should use `url: '/my/folder/submit.php'` as part of your ajax request? Does this help?

Comment: Yes!! Thank you. I feel so silly now! The only thing now is my echo command in the newfile.php does not echo back to the same webpage under the drop down list after it is selected. Any ideas / pointers to help would be so gratefully received.

Comment: Can you update the question to what you're looking to do and I'll put it into a single answer for you? Include some dummy data on `$js_array_leadersGroupsName` and `$js_array_students_lists`

Comment: Sorry, realise I didn't add the arrays with dummy data. Have added, but as not at computer I have mocked it up from memory.